# Reference request for books on the foundations of science

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request

I have lately been interested in the foundations of science. I checked Wikipedia if there was an article on the foundations of science, but there was no such article. So, I am asking for books and papers that discuss the foundations of science. I believe the Philosophy Stack Exchange is the best stack exchange for asking about references on the foundations of science.

Comment: It is a bit of a broad topic, probably as big as "epistemology", or almost. Each science will probably have its own "foundations", but there might as well be more or less common "foundations" to be found in epistemology.

Comment: You can consider Springer's journal: [Foundations of Science](https://www.springer.com/journal/10699)

Comment: And you can find useful material (with bibliography) into SEP, starting e.g. with [Science and Pseudo-Science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pseudo-science/).

Comment: Good starting point: K.R. Popper, T.S. Kuhn, P. Feyerabend, I. Hacking. Quite old but still interesting: H.Poincaré's [The Foundations of Science (1913)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Foundations_of_Science) and [Science and Method (1914)](https://books.google.it/books?id=QPXa2UgysLQC) and [Science and Hypothesis (1905)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Science_and_Hypothesis)

Comment: Not Feyerabend! :-)